# How do I find RDS clusters with 0 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

In the RDS UI, you can see clusters and easily identify those with 0 instances.  I'm trying to query RDS using AWS CLI, but I don't see anything offhand that will help me find that value.

I briefly looked at:

```
aws rds describe-db-clusters
```

and

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-endpoints
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to how I can determine which clusters have 0 instances?  Ideally via AWS CLI and via an SNS topic.

Thanks!

```
aws rds describe-db-clusters
```

and

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-endpoints
```

Don't seem to return the data I need to find out which clusters have 0 instances.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws rds describe-db-clusters` command gives you exactly what you want. You simply need to check for an empty `DBClusterMembers` array in the response. You can use a `query` expression to have the CLI return only those clusters:

```
aws rds describe-db-clusters --query 'DBClusters[?!not_null(DBClusterMembers)]'
```